# Custom Tensorflow Layer Which Diagonalizes + Trainable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to encode the following function into a TS layer.  Let x be a d-dimensional vector.
x -> tf.linalg.diag(x)*A + b,

where A is a *trainable* dxd matrix and b is a trainable (d-dimensional) vector.

If A and b were not there, I would have used a Lambda layer but since they are... how would I go about it.

---

*P.s.:  for educational perpouses I don't want to feed the lambda layer:*

```
Lambda(lambda x: tf.linalg.diag(x)))
```

*Into a fully-connected layer with "identity" activation.  (I know this works but it doesn't help me learn how to address the problem really :) )*

Comment: Just as a comment, when you write `tf.linalg.diag(x)*A`, is `*` element-wise multiplication or matrix product? If it is matrix product, it is the same as scaling every row of `A` by the corresponding value in `x`, so you can also simply do `tf.expand_dims(x, 1) * A` (here `*` would be element-wise multiplication). If it really was element-wise multiplication, an alternative expression could be `tf.linalg.diag(x * tf.linalg.diag_part(A))`, which is more verbose but might be slightly quicker (which, admittedly, would only be relevant if `A` is quite large).

Comment: Actually it is matrix mulitplication.  So I'll definetly include your tip :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your custom layer and put your function in call method.

```
class Custom_layer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, dim):
        super(Custom_layer, self).__init__()
        self.dim = dim

        # add trainable weight
        self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=(dim,dim),trainable=True)
        # add trainable bias
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(dim))

    def call(self, input):
        # your function
        return (tf.linalg.diag(input)*self.weight) + self.bias
    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Custom_layer, self).get_config()
        config['dim'] = self.dim
        return config
```

And use it just like normal layer and give it with dimension argument when you use it.

```
my_layer = Custom_layer(desire_dimension)
output = my_layer(input)
```

Comment: Maybe you did not import keras

Comment: yes you can. you can add as much variable as you like